# SSIS script task not branching when file does not exist

Tags: ssis, constraints

I've followed the suggestions on this and other sites to check if a file exists using a Script Task.  The code works perfectly (steps only run if the file exists) so long as I don't want to do some different processing if the file does not exist.  When I try to branch to different processing when the file does not exist that branch never executes and the package completes successfully without running the steps in the "file does not exist" branch.  Here's what the package is doing.

1. See if a header file exists.  If yes, go to step 2.  If no, go to step 4.
2. Process the header file
3. Delete the header file
4. See if a detail file exists.  If yes, go to step 5.  If no, stop processing
5. Process the detail file
6. Delete the detail file

**Package variables:**

blnFileExists: Boolean, defaults to False

strListIndexFileFullPath:  string, expression based upon other string variables that set file name and file path

**Script Task**

Properties:  FailPackageOnFailure:  False, FailParentOnFailure:  False

```
Imports System.IO
Public Sub Main()
    Dts.Variables("blnFileExists").Value = File.Exists(Dts.Variables("strListIndexFileFullPath").Value)
    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

Properties of "file exists" constraint > Evaluation operation:  Expression and Constraint, Value:  Success, Expression:  @blnFileExists==True, Using Logical AND

Properties of "file does not exist" constraint > Evaluation operation:  Expression and Constraint, Value:  Success, Expression:  @blnFileExists==False, Using Logical AND

Answer (score 3):

In the Precedence Constraint Editor, you need to change `Logical AND` to **Logical OR**.

In your scenario, you want the package to take either the path when `blnFileExists` value is *true* **or** the path when `blnFileExists` value is *false*. `(Notice the OR in the sentence)` If you set the constraint to `Logical AND`, then the package will expect both the expressions to succeed. It is not possible in this scenario because the variable `blnFileExists` can have only **true** or **false** and `not both`.

Having said that, you actually don't need to use `Script Task` to check if a file exists or not. You can make use of `File System Task` to do the same.

Please have a look at my answer in the below link to see how you can check whether a file exist or not using File System Task. When you use `File System Task`, you won't need to write any C# code or make use of expressions in precedence constraints.

[Branching after a file system task in SSIS without failing the package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493238/branching-after-a-file-system-task-in-ssis-without-failing-the-package/6716252#6716252)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Siva - Thank you VERY much.  The Logical OR was the answer.  Obvious now that you've pointed it out.  Thanks also for referencing your other solution - I had actually found that and tried to use, but I was still using Logical AND which explains why I couldn't get your solution to work.